# How do I make a different URL for every product on my website?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, product, webshop

So I'm working on an affiliate website and I'm trying to figure out how to get a different URL for every product on my website.

So let's say i've got a page called www.mywebsite.com/products with all the different products on there that I get from my database. When I click on one of the products it's supposed to go to the URL www.mywebsite.com/products/testproduct. If I click on a different product it's supposed to go to www.mywebsite.com/products/testproduct 2 etc...
How do I get a URL for every product on my product page? I've been searching for a long time and I'm sure it's an easy solution cause every webshop has this function, but I just can't really explain what I want to Google, so that's why I'm asking here.

Is there like a term for this that I can look up? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to search for "clean urls". Often also known as "semantic URLs" and used in conjunction with a RESTful interface. These search terms will put you on the right path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the website with a GET element.

So you list all your items on the page product/, and when you click on something it will link to testproduct/?id=[itemid]

Then you can use php

```
$_GET['id'];
```

and with that  you can request all details from the database and print them on the page.

No clue if that helped but that is what I would do.

EDIT: for security reasons (SQL injections) use:

```
filter_var($_GET["id"], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Comment: I suggest skipping the last recommandation, using prepared/parameterized queries should be enough to protect against SQL injection. filter_var is usually used to protect against XSS when outputting data.

Comment: This will not work the way he describes it. He doesn't seem to have a system in place to transform his database data (the products) into nice urls like the permalink system in WordPress.